# camel cxf - how to send soap request response in email

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, camel-cxf

```
Here is my spring configuration.

Spring.xml
-------------
<!-- Outgoing SOAP client endpoint -->
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceEndpoint" address="${endpointAddress}"
        wsdlURL="${wsdlAddress}" endpointName="${portName}" serviceName="${serviceName}">

        <!-- The interceptors - needed to log the SOAP requests and responses -->
        <!-- They can be removed, when no logging is needed -->
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
<cxf:properties>
            <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />          
        </cxf:properties>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

    <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
        <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="${disableHostnameCheck}">
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="${keystorePassword}">
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${keystorePassword}"
                    file="${keystoreLocation}" />
            </sec:keyManagers>
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${truststorePassword}"
                    file="${truststoreLocation}" />
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <!-- these filters ensure that a ciphersuite with export-suitable or 
                    null encryption is used, but exclude anonymous Diffie-Hellman key change 
                    as this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks -->
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
        </http:tlsClientParameters>
        <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"
            ReceiveTimeout="${connectionTimeout}" ConnectionTimeout="${connectionTimeout}" />
    </http:conduit>

Here is the Camel route configuration
-------------
<from ...
<to uri="cxf:bean:serviceEndpoint" />

This works well and we can have the soap request/response logged into the log file. Here soap request with soap header is generated by cxf.
```

Do we have a way to capture the soap request and response into camel Exchange? I have to send an email attached with soap request and response if the service call is failed. 
Have tried using thread local but it doesn't seems to work expected.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

You have it in CXF Interceptors - take a look at them.

I guess, you can send your e-mail out of it.

Start from `org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor` class - there are bunch of different ones for different phases.

P.S. From first glance `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor` and 
`org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor` could be good candidates...